# How so I stop a shared method from running with class and extends?

Tags: javascript, subclass

I am creating two classes, `Rectangle` and `Square`, based on the example shown on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes).

Since Rectangle is the prototype of Square, they share the same method `area()`.

However, I want `area()` to run only if `length === height` for the square.

I've tried to add an if-statement after super(), but it area() still returns this.length* this.height regardless of an erroneous input.

I could add an `if-statement` in the `area()` method, but I did not because it would not make sense when we are calculating the area of a rectangle.

```js
class Rectangle {
  constructor(length, height){
    this.length = length;
    this.height = height;
  }
  area(){
    return this.length*this.height;
  }
}

class Square extends Rectangle {
  constructor(length, height){ // have area() return "Not a square" instead of a number
    super(length, height);
    if (length !== height) {
      console.log("Not a square.")
    }
    this.name = "square";
  }
}

const rectangle = new Rectangle(2,3);
console.log(rectangle.area());

const square = new Square(5,2);
console.log(square.area())
```

Comment: "*have area() return "Not a square"*" - no, don't do that. Just make your constructor (not the `area` method!) throw an exception when trying to create a non-square `Square`.

Comment: I see! So I should stop check the input inside the constructor to stop an erroneous input at the very beginning. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can throw an error when the criteria is not matched. This will stop the construction of the object.

```
class Square extends Rectangle {
  constructor(length, height){ 
    super(length, height);
    if (length !== height) {
      throw new Error("not a square");
    }
    this.name = "square";
  }
}

... 


try {
  const notASquare = new Square(10,20); // This will throw an error
} catch(e) {
  console.log(e)
}
```

**However**

in this case i think it makes more sence to only accept 1 parameter to prevent this error from happening:

```
class Square extends Rectangle {
  constructor(size) {
    super(size, size); // Passing size 2 times makes sure length and height for a square are always equal
    this.name = "square";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! throw new Error() seems to stop the entire application from running, though. If I don't want one error to stop the remaining code from running, should I instead create another area() method on the square?

Comment: If there is the posibility of an error, you should catch it with a try-catch block (as described in the answer). This will prevent the rest of the application from stopping.

Comment: Ok, will study that. Thank you!

Comment: In my opinion the Square constructor with only one dimension is the better way to do it